# Q: Acumos : I don't know what is difference between "Acumos Portal Marketplace Users" and "Acumos Operations" written in documentation

Tags: machine-learning, installation, difference, acumos

Now I am trying to use Acumos AI platform.
While looking Acumos Documentation, I think I can use Acumos AI services via web portal.
But,I see "One click Deploy User Guide" in document. Do I have to install Acumos AI to use it?

Can't I use Acumos AI service through only web portal?
What is a difference between web portal(Portal and Marketplace) an Acumos installation?

Answer (score 0):

The Acumos project in cooperation with the Linux Foundation maintain the web site  https://marketplace.acumos.org but this server only offers read access, for example it does not allow users to on-board new models.  If you would like to use the full suite of Acumos features and services such as on-boarding new models, deploy a new instance of Acumos in in your own private network.  The All-In-One (AIO) feature is designed to make it easy & fast to deploy your own instance of Acumos to a Kubernetes environment.